# Why $locationChangeStart fires repeatedly when event.preventDefault is called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
            if (!$window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this view?')){
              event.preventDefault();
            }
      });
```

When I do this, and click on '**cancel**', the confirm box keeps coming again and again (I checked that the control is reaching the `preventDefault` line). On clicking '**Ok**', the url changes correctly. What can be the issue ?

Angular version is **1.2.16**. The above code is similar to [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/NycOKi?p=preview) plunkr where it seems to work even though the version there is even older